# Format a phone number in Shopify's Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

How does one go about formatting a phone number in Shopify using Liquid? The `shop.phone` object seems to output in a way that is specific to shop settings.

Answer (score 1):

Much can be accomplished with only a few [Liquid filters](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters).

For example, we wanted to make phone numbers clickable within email notifications. Below is how `shop.phone` outputs the number for our shop.

**(555) 555-5555**

Fortunately, the filter method outputs directly to the page so there is no need to assign a variable.

```
{{ shop.phone | remove: "(" | remove: ")" | replace: " ", "-" }}
```

Our finished snippet looked like this:

```
<a href="tel:1-{{ shop.phone | remove: "(" | remove: ")" | replace: " ", "-" }}">{{shop.phone}}</a>
```